# What is the use-case for MNT_EXPIRE?

Tags: linux, unmounting

From [`umount(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umount.2.html):

> `MNT_EXPIRE` (since Linux 2.6.8)
>
> Mark the mount point as expired.  If a mount point is not currently in use, then an initial call to `umount2()` with this flag fails with the error `EAGAIN`, but marks the mount point as expired.  The mount point remains expired as long as it isn't accessed by any process.  A second `umount2()` call specifying `MNT_EXPIRE` unmounts an expired mount point.  This flag cannot be specified with either `MNT_FORCE` or `MNT_DETACH`.

What is the use-case for `MNT_EXPIRE`? How is it useful?

What is different about an "expired" mount point?

Links:

- https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/issues/497

Answer (score 1):

It is used to unmount a filesystem after a period of inactivity.

Systemd [automount units](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.automount.html) implement such a feature, for example.

Comment: Interesting. I imagine then that a daemon would simply call `umount(MNT_EXPIRE)` periodically, and if no process had accessed the mount in the last period it would be unmounted.